My questions and answers aren't immediately appearing when I click "Submit"
This has happened twice now, on two separate SE sites: I type an answer, click "Submit", and when the page refreshes, my answer isn't there. The answer does get submitted, and does appear the next time I refresh the page, but it still leads to a brief moment of panic that it might not have been submitted and I'll be forced to type it out all over again.
Indeed, when I submitted this very Meta question, it took me to a 404 page, and I had to refresh to get to the actual submitted question. So questions are being affected as well.
Has anyone else experienced this issue, and can it be looked into?

This began occurring within the last hour on both Meta SE and Meta SU (it didn't occur when I posted this question on Meta SE, but did on both subsequent edits, as well as an edit to this Meta SU question ~5m ago)

It may be related, may just as well be not, but I've noticed today that when casting binding spam flags or the close/delete vote combo from the 'lost souls' script, the page refreshes and the thing I just deleted doesn't seem deleted. I was blaming it on 'slow internet today'.

@JW0914 it's at least from yesterday. Certainly not as recent as 2 hours ago (one hour before you commented).

This problem occurs at least since 2024-06-25 20:37:03Z on tex.se

Most likely another mistake in same bunch of old jQuery code upgrade. :/

Status tag change doesn't correspond with a recent change, just cleanup. I left this in [status-planned] and forgot about it. My bad.

@Slate Makes sense. Out of curiosity, why close and reopen this question three times?

@Sonic The change that was stopping Q&A from appearing immediately on submit was also stopping unilateral closures (which I can do) from appearing instantly. I was using unilateral closure both as a test of reproducibility as we were testing a few things, and as a proxy for whether the reported issue was resolved. This was the best test question available for that use case.

We've made a change that should significantly reduce, or completely eliminate, the frequency with which this problem occurs. We expect that this problem affected a variety of actions around the network at random, including certain close votes, delete votes, flags, answers, and the like.
If you're still seeing this problem with any significant frequency, please let me know:

What action you were trying to perform, and
How often you're seeing the problem

...in the comments here and I'll pass it along to devs.

Possibly related/unrelated, but I've been getting the "you've already undone your vote on this comment" when first upvoting a comment, but it seems like the vote is actually applying fine, just getting the error message; the first time I observed it would have been right around the time this answer was posted, could it be related? If not I can make another report unless someone helpfully beats me to it.

With a little more science it's possible this is only happening if I am a moderator on the site in question.

Bug report for the above behavior that @BryanKrause mentioned.

Possibly related:  (1) click the link to delete a comment; (2) a dialog pops up asking if you really want to delete the comment; (3) click either "Cancel" or "OK"; (4) the comment is deleted!  The fact that the dialog is irrelevant is... weird, but also the fact that it exists at all.  I've never seen it before.

Bug report for the above behavior that @XanderHenderson mentioned (in case anyone sees this here and wants to track the status of that getting fixed; it's already been marked for review).

Don't recall seeing this since, looks like it's been resolved.

Since few days ago (maybe yesterday) any mod action I make on the post (questions and answers), like close voting, delete voting, undelete, spam flagging are no longer immediately applied on the post and I need to do a page reload to see the change.
The number of close votes or delete votes on the post is refreshed, but not the fact that my action changed the status of the post into closed, deleted, undeleted.
If there is pending flag on the post, the actions on a flag are also not refreshed accordingly as they used to be.
This behavior is not always visible, and occasionally the action works as expected.
Posting question on SOfT also results with 404 page.

Yesterday. A developer "upgraded" jQuery code, breaking some things while doing it, so most likely this is one of those.

Probably would have been better to perform testing before making changes on live servers.

I have noticed that. It seems to not be limited to posting - I also dupe-hammered a post, the page automatically refreshed (as usual) but the post was not marked as a dupe. After I manually refreshed it, it then was.
It seems that the page navigation happens before the action (post, hammer, etc) is applied.
I am not sure which actions are affected by this. Potentially any that leads to a page refresh or navigation.
This seems to be at least from yesterday but it is inconsistent when it shows up.

OK, also occurred when I posted this answer.

When I posted mine, it was not immediately visible, too.

Due to the timing and the similarity, I suspect this is also related. Since about a day or so ago, I've noticed on several occasions that when there were 4 close votes on a question and I cast the final vote, the page displays the question as still being open, and there are no pending close votes. In the past, the page always refreshed to show it was closed. Nonetheless, manually refreshing does then cause the page to be properly displayed.
Notes:

Just like the question states and several others have also noticed, when I posted this answer, it didn't immediately appear either.
About 90 minutes after Slate's answer was posted, I cast the final close vote on Math SE's A limit involving fractional parts, with it then appropriately immediately updating its display. Thus, it seems the change mentioned in Slate's answer has at least resolved the problem I describe here.

